# Split a wide data-frame into multiple columns to convert into long format

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a time-series of air quality measurements from multiple sensors (A and B) in a data.frame.

```
df<-data.frame(time=seq(ISOdatetime(2001,2,3,0,0,0), ISOdatetime(2001,2,4,0,0,0), by=(60*5)),A=runif(289),B=runif(289))
```

I would like to pivot_longer but run out of memory.

How can I pivot each combination of time and A, then time and B using split?

```
df %>% 
dplyr::pivot_longer() #This is the output I would like
```

but complains about error allocating memory

Comment: Can you show your expeceted output

Comment: Not clear what you want - do you mean the output of ``df %>% pivot_longer(-time)``?

Answer (score 1):

I think that in this given situation that `tidyr::pivot_longer` is the best option. I tried a few different options and `pivot_longer` still out performs the other options.

First, I created a function to split into individual dataframes, put into long format, then bind the rows back together.

```
library(tidyverse)

longer <- function(x) {
  y <- x %>%
    dplyr::select(-B) %>%
    tidyr::pivot_longer(-time)
  
  z <- x %>%
    dplyr::select(-A) %>%
    tidyr::pivot_longer(-time)
  
  rbind(y, z)
}
```

Second, you can do a split by using arbitrary groups, then change to long format, then bind data back together.

```
df %>%
  dplyr::mutate(group = rep(1:2, length.out = nrow(.))) %>%
  dplyr::group_by(group) %>%
  dplyr::group_split() %>%
  purrr::map(., tidyr::pivot_longer, -c(time, group)) %>%
  dplyr::bind_rows() %>%
  dplyr::ungroup() %>%
  dplyr::select(-group)
```

You can see when running `bench::mark` that `pivot_longer` still out performs the others.

```
bench::mark(
  one = longer(df) %>% arrange(value),
  two = df %>%
    dplyr::mutate(group = rep(1:2, length.out = nrow(.))) %>% 
    dplyr::group_by(group) %>% 
    dplyr::group_split() %>% 
    purrr::map(., tidyr::pivot_longer,-c(time, group)) %>%
    dplyr::bind_rows() %>% 
    dplyr::ungroup() %>% 
    dplyr::select(-group) %>% arrange(value),
  three = tidyr::pivot_longer(df,-time) %>% arrange(value)
)[c(1,3,5,7)]
```

Output

```
# A tibble: 3 × 4
  expression   median mem_alloc n_itr
  <bch:expr> <bch:tm> <bch:byt> <int>
1 one         11.68ms   127.5KB    43
2 two         18.27ms   118.4KB    26
3 three        5.73ms    60.8KB    84
```

For using split (#2 here), as you increase the number of groups, you also get an increase in time and memory.

```
# A tibble: 5 × 4
  expression     median mem_alloc n_itr
  <bch:expr>   <bch:tm> <bch:byt> <int>
1 one group      12.3ms     112KB    33
2 two groups     17.5ms     118KB    27
3 three groups   21.5ms     131KB    22
4 four groups    24.9ms     144KB    20
5 five groups    29.4ms     157KB    16
```